# What exactly is shellcode?

Tags: shellcode

What is shellcode and how does it work? I used to think it was just a binary string encoded with hex, but I recently started reading more and it seems it is something completely different. I know it is used by malware, but what exactly is shellcode and how does it work? Also, how can I write my own shellcode, for example, if I have a "hello world" program written in python, how do I convert that program into shellcode and make it work in the same way?

Comment: This'll probably end up getting closed as too broad, so let me suggest you read [Shellcode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) to get the basic stuff out of the way, then come back with whatever thought-provoking questions remain.

Comment: I have heard the term "shellcode" get abused to mean various other things, like rootkits that used a web attack vector.  Just watch out; not everybody wields the English language and its terms appropriately at all times  :-)